# How to initialize and assign value to constant in constructor?

Tags: truffle, erc-20, solidity-0.7.x

I have the following code and want to initialize a constant in constructor.

```
 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
    contract IToken is ERC20 { 
        uint256 private constant _Total;// = 1000 * 10**9;
        

constructor(string memory Name, string memory Symbol) public ERC20(Name, Symbol) {
            _Total = 1000 * 10**9;
            _mint(msg.sender, _Total);
        }
     }
```

However I get an errors that the constant are

> TypeError: Uninitialized "constant" variable.
> TypeError: Cannot assign to a constant variable.

I want to initialize the constant in the constructor argument so that when I deploy the token I can deploy it with following statement in truffle by specifying _Total in deploy script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> uint256 private constant _Total;// = 1000 * 10**9;

If you declare something as [`constant`](http://uint256%20private%20constant%20_Total;//%20=%201000%20*%2010**9;) you must initialise it at the same time. You can't set its value at a later date. (Its value must be known at compile time, so you can't set it during execution.)

In your constructor you are not passing in the value that you want to set `_Total` to, so there's no real need to set it in the constructor - you can just hard-code it as a global variable in the contract.

So, two options:

1. Change `uint256 private constant _Total;` to `uint256 private _Total;`, and then pass a value into the constructor, and set `_Total`.
2. Just set `uint256 private constant _Total = 1000 * 10**9;` as a global variable.

> want to initialize the constant in the constructor argument so that when I deploy the token I can deploy it with following statement in truffle by specifying _Total in deploy script.

In that case you want option #1.

Comment: I want to pass the value from deploy script thats why I am not assigning value. But anyway the answer you suggested is what I have already implemented in my code.

Comment: My point #1 removes the `constant` keyword, which is what you'll need to do.

Answer (score 2):

For **assigning** a **constant variable** to the **constructor**,

Use **immutable**. It is a **variant** of **constructor**.
It also runs once when deploying the smart contract, no one can change that variable value after deploying.

**immutable** can be used as **inline** or in a **constructor** function both.

But here is the catch,
**immutable** takes little more gas than **constructor**.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `constant` you can use `immutable` for the variable. An `immutable` variable can be initialised in the constructor but can not be modified afterwards as the value is made part of the bytecode.

Read more about that in the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/contracts.html#immutable)